# Testing RingCental APIs with Postman

Tags: postman, ringcentral

The RingCentral API Explorer allows to select the app and start testing all the APIs, but what I prefer is testing the APIs with Postman as it is easier and flexible.

While I am testing the APIs with Postman clients, I was look if there are any ready-made Postman collection available which I can simply import and start testing the RingCentral APIs with minimum changes.

I haven't found any available collection for RingCentral APIs in the net. Is there any existing API Postman collection available which is been used by RingCentral developers and tester?

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for https://developers.ringcentral.com/engage/digital/guide/postman

Answer (score 2):

There are some postman collections available, but not sure if those are updated.  However you can try these following importing to your Postman client:

https://github.com/grokify/ringcentral-postman
and
http://ringcentral.github.io/api-specs/specs_engage_engage-digital_postman-2.0.json

ref: https://developers.ringcentral.com/engage/digital/guide/postman
You can try importing into your postman and start testing, create different environment.
Alternately there is also Swagger 2.0 to Postman 2.0 converter which will convert Swagger collection to Postman.
You can find the reference and Swagger collection here:
https://community.ringcentral.com/questions/629/postman-collection.html

Answer (score 0):

1. Navigate to the API reference page. It looks like this:

[image: API reference]

1. Fill out the information. In this example you'd add a `person ID`.
2. Click `Try it out` and follow the instructions.
3. The cURL command on the right will automatically update with your auth information.
4. Open Postman.
5. Click the `Import` button, located on top left corner.
6. Click the `Raw Text` tab.
7. Paste the generated cURL command in the text feild.

Postman will automatically generate the authorization headers and body. Once you do this once you can use it as a template for all other API's using Postman.